# Прием сообщений с последующей обработкой

Tags: php, алгоритм, email, автоматизация

Пользователи отправляют сообщения на почту. 
Как реализовать следующее: Чтобы после получения каждого входящего письма, срабатывал некий скрипт, который будет например отправлять тему и тело письма в ЦРМ систему.

Answer (score 1):

если нет административного доступа к машине, принимающей почту, то надо на php использовать связку из [imap_open](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imap-open.php), [imap_search](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imap-search.php), [imap_body](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imap-body.php) и т.п.

обратите внимание, например на [этот вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7363077/4827341) и ответы к нему.

Comment: доступ есть к почте. (на собственном домене)

Comment: тогда можете воспользоваться средствами smtp-сервера и вызывать при поступлении письма какой-нибудь обработчик. ключевые слова для поиска: «piping email to script». но я не уверен, что для вас это будет проще, чем предложенное в ответе.